# Set different spacings in a GraphicsGrid

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts, spacing

I have a `GraphicsGrid` with some pictures and I want to create some sort of a headline for each column like this:

```
pic = Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"];
GraphicsGrid[{{"ocelot1", "ocelot2", "ocelot3"}, {pic, pic, 
   pic}, {pic, pic, pic}}]
```

However, the "row spacings" of the text cells are way too large and I want to somehow make them smaller such that it looks more like a headline (such that the text is right on top of the pic with narrow spacings).

Is there a way to do this, or alternatively, another/better/easier way to create some sort of headline for a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Grid` has plenty of options

```
Grid[{{"ocelot1", "ocelot2", "ocelot3"}, {pic, pic, pic}, {pic, pic, pic}},
 Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks eldo! I tried to use the Spacings option with GraphicsGrid which did not work, but with Grid it works well it seems. Good to know!

Comment: `Grid` is much more flexible than `GraphicsGrid`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Grid` as in @eldo's answer. However, if you have to use `GraphicsGrid` you can use negative `Spacings` as follows:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{"ocelot1", "ocelot2", "ocelot3"}, {pic, pic, pic}, {pic, pic, pic}}, 
 Spacings -> {Automatic, {2 -> Scaled[-.5]}}]
```

[image]